# Finding which range of numbers has the most occurrence in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, radix

The complexity I have to follow is o(n) so I am not allowed to use nested loops. I have a rough idea on what I want to do however I am not sure how to store the lower bound of the range.
The objective is to find the lower bound for the interval that holds the most elements.
We denote L as the length of range. What I've tried is:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,12] #after sorting by radix
L = 3

for i in range(len(lst)): 
    lower_bound[i] = i
    upper_bound[i] = i + L  #in this case L = 3.

    #if i is in range of certain i and its upper_bound,
    #increment count for that interval
    # e.g. 1 is in range of 0-3, so count for lower_bound[1] will +1.
    # e.g. 6 is in range of 4-6, so count for lower_bound[4] will +3.

#return the lower_bound with max count
```

So for this example, 3 will be returned, since 3-6 has 7 elements (prioritising the minimum lower bound).
I'm not sure if this is the right approach :(  Does this look correct, given the complexity is o(n)?

Comment: If with n you mean the length of the list then no, it's not o(n).

Comment: The task is pretty unclear, btw, better add a proper specification and example.

Comment: Looks like you just dumped that here and then immediately walked away. I guess you're not really interested in our help after all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem properly, it might be solved using two-pointers approach.

Set the left pointer (index) to the `0`, then move right index until element difference between `lst[right]` and `lst[left]` becomes larger than `L`.

Remember index difference `right - left`

Move left index until element difference becomes smaller than `L`

Move right index again, compare new index difference with current one, get max.

Repeat until end of the list